# simpler way to filter out nan or invalid's in Python array or a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I have numpy array `heights` which may have `nan`'s in it. I clean it by doing:

```
heights = numpy.asarray([ h for h in heights if not numpy.isnan(h) ])
```

This seems like a rather verbose way to express such a simple/common thing. I often have to do this as well for filtering my arrays in other ways and have to fall back on array building, which works but I bet there is a better way to do it. E.g. filtering by range...

```
heights = numpy.asarray(heights[lowerBound <= heights & heights < upperBound])
```

fails *in python*, where heights is still a numpy array. I fall back to doing...

EDIT: The error message for this line is:

*TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*

/EDIT

```
heights = numpy.asarray(heights[[h for h in heights if lowerBound <= h and h < upperBound]])
```

Gross. I've been using python for a 2-3 months now, but I'm still not really getting how to effectively and simply use the numpy masking system. I came from heavily using matlab, where a "mask" would be an array of booleans of the same shape/size. E.g.

```
heights = heights(~isnan(heights));
```

or alternatively...

```
heights(isnan(heights)) = [];
```

Both of these look super clean. Also, the bounds example that fails in python works in matlab, although the brackets must be changed to parentheses...

```
heights = heights(lowerBound <= heights & heights < upperBound)
```

How can i write these simple data transformations similarly elegantly in python/numpy, pythonic or otherwise?

Comment: Read this http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
heights[(10<=heights) & (heights<=90)]
```

This fails with an error about ambiguous truth value

```
heights[10<=heights & heights<=90]
```

You should have specified the error, not just say it 'fails'.  The error message gives us some clues as to why it fails. It usually means that it's trying to do a simple 'if then' evaluation with a boolean array, though it isn't obvious in this case how that is happening.

```
10<=heights & heights<=90  # also fails
(10<=heights) & (heights<=90) # fine
heights & heights<=90 # ok
20<=(heights & heights)<=80  # same error
20<=heights<=80  # error
20<=heights[0]<=80  # True
```

It took a bit of digging, but I now think the problem was with a mixing of Python and numpy range evaluation.  Python has a 2 sided boolean comparison that works with a single value.  numpy does not have that.  Without (), it first performs `heights & heights` and then tries to apply the single value Python operation, resulting in the `ambiguous boolean` error.

In general though, boolean indexing or masking works just as well in `numpy` as it does in `MATLAB`.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 8):

It works exactly like Matlab but with slightly different syntax

```
heights = heights[~np.isnan(heights)]
```

Demo

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> heights = np.array([1.0, 3.0, np.nan, -10.0])
>>> np.asarray([ h for h in heights if not np.isnan(h) ])
array([  1.,   3., -10.])
>>> heights[~np.isnan(heights)]
array([  1.,   3., -10.])
>>>
```

Comment: I actually didn't know that `numpy` supported `~`.  I was always using `np.logical_not` lol.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: what about for array OR or array AND

Comment: @user27886 - Using `&` and `|` should suffice.  That I know.

Comment: @raryeng See the 2nd code snippet in my post. That fails for me.

Comment: @user27886 - `&` and `|` only work for `bool` type `numpy` arrays.  You'll probably want to use `np.logical_and` and `np.logical_not`.  They can handle any `numpy` array.

Comment: You can see the infix operators in the docs for each of the functions http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.bitwise.html (look for the text "This ufunc implements the C/Python operator")

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning `np.isfinite` which will filter out NaN's, Inf's etc.  For the OP's case `heights[np.isfinite(heights)]`.  Of course, if you want to keep +/-Inf as valid values, you'll want `~np.isnan(data)` instead of `isfinite`.